# Which one is more natural: "extend the quarantine", "extend the quarantine period" or "extend the period of (the) quarantine"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is more natural: *extend the quarantine*, *extend the quarantine*, *extend*  *the period of quarantine*, *extend  the period of the quarantine*? For example:

> The authorities has decided to **extend the quarantine**.
>
> The authorities has decided to **extend the quarantine period**.
>
> The authorities has decided to extend **the period of quarantine**.
>
> The authorities has decided to extend **the period of the quarantine**.

Comment: You know editing is not done around here. **You have to decide whether to use it as an adjective or noun**.

Comment: *'Authorities **have** decided to extend the period of quarantine'* sounds OK to me.

Comment: Do I have to omit "the" before "authorities"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of those choices can be used, and they're all fairly natural.  The choice is mainly one of style and feel.  In general, the more words you use the less forceful or active it will sound, but other than that there's not much difference.